# Get parent view width/height from child's alignmentGuide modifier in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a `ZStack` with views that are center aligned; one of the views needs to be aligned at the bottom right corner. I don't want to create another `ZStack` and want to use `alignmentGuide`, is there a way to do this? I also don't want to hard code the parent's dimensions, ideally. Here is the code I have so far:

```
ZStack {
    Rectangle().foregroundColor(.blue)
    Text("CENTERED")
    Text("RIGHT BOTTOM")
        .fontWeight(.black)
        .alignmentGuide(HorizontalAlignment.center) { (viewDimensions) -> CGFloat in

            // If I had access to parent's width here, I could do something like:
            // return parent.width - viewDimensions.width
            return 0
    }.alignmentGuide(VerticalAlignment.center) { (viewDimensions) -> CGFloat in
        return 0
    }
}
```

Here is a quick preview of what the above looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is simpler solution...

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

[image: demo]

```
ZStack {
    Rectangle().foregroundColor(.blue)
        .overlay(
            Text("RIGHT BOTTOM").fontWeight(.black)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottomTrailing)
        )
    Text("CENTERED")
}
```

Comment: My question is specifically around using `alignmentGuide`, is there no way of doing this with alignment guides?